Handlebars site unable to locate files with all references confirmed correct
I am a new developer. I have been working with Handlebars and have come across a problem that AI can't seem to solve. After creating and testing several forms successfully, eventually I create a form and the routes stop working for that form. Then I try one of the earlier forms, and that's broken too. All references and file locations are confirmed correct, but the app can't find the form views. I've started a new app and rebuilt three times only to eventually encounter the same problem with forms all over again. I've theorized a few possible factors:

Deleting and renaming too many files?
CSRF token issues? Deprecation?
View caching in the browser?
Anyone have any ideas about this?

Tried rebuilding. Tried renaming files and folders, did not work. Ai can't help. All routes are correct and yet I get a 404 error on that form. I'm wondering if this is a known Handlebars or CSRF problem?
